# Adding dynamical options to PHP populated Dropdown from SQLServer Database

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, drop-down-menu

need some input

i know how to populate a php dropdown list from MSSQLServer Datebase and save the selected value in the datebase, but i want to add new dynamical entrys in the dropdown menu and save them into the database. Here is the code:

some help?

Comment: Where `$result` come from?

Comment: from the sql querey just to populate the dropdown, simple select:
$sta = $connection->query("SELECT StatusID, Status FROM Master.dbo.Status");
    $sta->execute();
    $result = $sta->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

i thinks its not nessecary for my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend doing all this in the SQL level, try this
it is modified from a stored procedure I use in a similar fashion

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[MergeStatus](
    @StatusID int,
    @Status Varchar(8000)
    )
AS

BEGIN
set nocount on;


Merge [Master.dbo.Status] as Target
using   (select  @StatusID As ID) As source
On
(Target.StatusID = source.ID)
When Matched Then
         INSERT INTO Master.dbo.AllgemeineAngaben (StatusID) VALUES (@StatusID ) -- we have a match ID is Greater than 0 so insert into new tabke
When Not Matched Then
  Insert   ( 
            @Status -- no match add new to Master.dbo.Status
            )

  Values(
            @Status
    );



    IF @StatusID IS NULL or @StatusID = 0 -- our ID is not waht we expected so we need to insert 
            BEGIN
                SET @Id = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as [int]);--getting ID od record we just inserted
                INSERT INTO Master.dbo.AllgemeineAngaben (StatusID) VALUES (@StatusID ) 

            END



END
```

Comment: sry i have no idea where I should implement that. it's so different from my code.